# Why do I see cannot resolve symbol on main method while editting configurations on Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA, and I am trying to edit configurations for an imported Gradle project. It says "Cannot resolve symbol udacity."

[image: Here is the picture of it]

What can I do to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does the defined main class exist?

Comment: Yes, the defined main class exits

Answer (score 0):

So you have git cloned the project to a folder `ud282-master` and there is a subfolder in there `Project 1 - TicTacToe`.

In Intellij if you have another project open go to *File -> New -> Project From Existing Sources...* or if you don't have a project open go to *Import project*.

In both cases pick the folder `Project 1 - TicTacToe` to import from because that's where the gradle files are. In the next screen pick *Import project from external model -> Gradle*.

Then you should be able to make a new Run Configuration specifying in *Use classpath or module* the module `Project_1_-_TicTacToe_main` and not `Project 1 - TicTacToe`. Then just pick `com.udacity.Game` from the dropdown.

Comment: I have done all of these things already, but they didn't work. I think it still doesn't recognize packages.